# Why does mlr give different results in different runs even when using set.seed()?

Tags: r, reproducible-research, mlr

To publish reproducible results obtained in the `mlr` package one should use the `set.seed()` function to control the randomness of the code.

Testing, it seems such practice doesn't lead to the desired results, in which different runs of the code give slightly different outputs, such as reported in the [source of this question and following code](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/938).

---

Here's some reproducible code

```r
## libraries
library(mlr)
library(parallel)
library(parallelMap)

## options
set.seed(1)
cv.n <- 3
bag.n <- 3

## data
dataset <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(15000), ncol=5))
dataset$target <- factor(c(rep(0, 1500), rep(1, 1500)))

## task
classif.task <- makeClassifTask(id="dataset", data=dataset, target="target", positive="1")

## resampling strategy
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=cv.n)

## number of features and observations
nf <- getTaskNFeats(classif.task)
no <- getTaskSize(classif.task)

# training and test set
train.set <- sample(no, size = round(0.8*no))
test.set <- setdiff(seq(no), train.set)

## learners
# decision tree
dt.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.rpart")
dt.lrn <- setPredictType(dt.lrn, predict.type="prob")
# random forest
rf.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")
rf.lrn <- setPredictType(rf.lrn, predict.type="prob")
# neural network
nn.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.nnet", MaxNWts=5000, trace=FALSE)
nn.lrn <- makeBaggingWrapper(nn.lrn, bw.iters=bag.n)
nn.lrn <- setPredictType(nn.lrn, predict.type="prob")
# support vector machine
svm.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.svm", kernel="radial")
svm.lrn <- makeBaggingWrapper(svm.lrn, bw.iters=bag.n)
svm.lrn <- setPredictType(svm.lrn, predict.type="prob")
# gradient boosting machine
gbm.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.gbm", distribution="adaboost")
gbm.lrn <- makeBaggingWrapper(gbm.lrn, bw.iters=bag.n)
gbm.lrn <- setPredictType(gbm.lrn, predict.type="prob")

## benchmark
lrns <- list(dt.lrn, rf.lrn, nn.lrn, svm.lrn, gbm.lrn)
parallelStartMulticore(detectCores(), level="mlr.resample")
for (i in 1:5) {
    bmrk <- suppressMessages(benchmark(lrns, subsetTask(classif.task, subset=train.set), rdesc, measures=list(mmce, acc, auc, tpr, tnr, ppv, f1)))
print(bmrk)
}
parallelStop()
```

And here's the result:

```r
  task.id           learner.id mmce.test.mean acc.test.mean auc.test.mean tpr.test.mean tnr.test.mean ppv.test.mean f1.test.mean
1 dataset        classif.rpart      0.5050000     0.4950000     0.5035564     0.5857604     0.4216936     0.5001443    0.5132852
2 dataset classif.randomForest      0.5141667     0.4858333     0.4835233     0.4811167     0.4913591     0.4813667    0.4805184
3 dataset  classif.nnet.bagged      0.4841667     0.5158333     0.5130378     0.5134648     0.5132865     0.5065907    0.5053251
4 dataset   classif.svm.bagged      0.5200000     0.4800000     0.4783791     0.4596055     0.5038720     0.4754137    0.4634932
5 dataset   classif.gbm.bagged      0.5175000     0.4825000     0.4999211     0.5681540     0.4307022           NaN    0.4079824
  task.id           learner.id mmce.test.mean acc.test.mean auc.test.mean tpr.test.mean tnr.test.mean ppv.test.mean f1.test.mean
1 dataset        classif.rpart      0.5095833     0.4904167     0.4887304     0.5896894     0.3914619     0.4875778    0.5309759
2 dataset classif.randomForest      0.4920833     0.5079167     0.5094901     0.4981170     0.5180616     0.5037475    0.5005092
3 dataset  classif.nnet.bagged      0.5037500     0.4962500     0.5007292     0.5182091     0.4794809     0.4894119    0.4873004
4 dataset   classif.svm.bagged      0.4870833     0.5129167     0.5243128     0.4687382     0.5571168     0.5102900    0.4867651
5 dataset   classif.gbm.bagged      0.5041667     0.4958333     0.5037020     0.3307626     0.6699108           NaN    0.2177101
  task.id           learner.id mmce.test.mean acc.test.mean auc.test.mean tpr.test.mean tnr.test.mean ppv.test.mean f1.test.mean
1 dataset        classif.rpart      0.5154167     0.4845833     0.4997415     0.6023993     0.3909165           NaN    0.4194502
2 dataset classif.randomForest      0.5058333     0.4941667     0.5092414     0.4792270     0.5101295     0.4898916    0.4837489
3 dataset  classif.nnet.bagged      0.4900000     0.5100000     0.5113847     0.6091273     0.4093971     0.5044188    0.5500985
4 dataset   classif.svm.bagged      0.5025000     0.4975000     0.5093498     0.4597310     0.5386824     0.4937899    0.4711354
5 dataset   classif.gbm.bagged      0.5045833     0.4954167     0.4966777     0.3333333     0.6666667           NaN    0.2181105
  task.id           learner.id mmce.test.mean acc.test.mean auc.test.mean tpr.test.mean tnr.test.mean ppv.test.mean f1.test.mean
1 dataset        classif.rpart      0.5116667     0.4883333     0.4816318    0.40531599     0.5665951     0.4699498   0.42524328
2 dataset classif.randomForest      0.4966667     0.5033333     0.5088898    0.48810185     0.5189027     0.4994051   0.49328978
3 dataset  classif.nnet.bagged      0.5229167     0.4770833     0.4914172    0.35887024     0.5964164     0.4683719   0.40099597
4 dataset   classif.svm.bagged      0.5016667     0.4983333     0.4926987    0.49163773     0.5047228     0.4935696   0.49220550
5 dataset   classif.gbm.bagged      0.5016667     0.4983333     0.4918831    0.04242424     0.9485944           NaN   0.06559572
  task.id           learner.id mmce.test.mean acc.test.mean auc.test.mean tpr.test.mean tnr.test.mean ppv.test.mean f1.test.mean
1 dataset        classif.rpart      0.5016667     0.4983333     0.4928826     0.4982873     0.4894108     0.4845022    0.4687902
2 dataset classif.randomForest      0.5050000     0.4950000     0.4945688     0.4973200     0.4935429     0.4909559    0.4936415
3 dataset  classif.nnet.bagged      0.5137500     0.4862500     0.4818591     0.4314678     0.5387981     0.4780440    0.4533055
4 dataset   classif.svm.bagged      0.5054167     0.4945833     0.4962764     0.5692158     0.4246046     0.4932935    0.5251290
5 dataset   classif.gbm.bagged      0.5129167     0.4870833     0.4852225     0.2393787     0.7450389           NaN    0.1945371
```

You can see different runs give different numerical outputs. And this is true among every classifier, from the most stochastic ones to the least.

---

What can I do to ensure reproducible results?

Comment: Note I did not accept my answer because it's possible someone may have a solution that works in other OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in [this comment](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/938#issuecomment-226018781), the code above is run **with parallelization**. To ensure the reproducibility in every parallel run one should use `set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")`, if you don't use Windows<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1. Windows doesn't support forks, which are used in this multicore case for the `parallel` library.</sub>